# Firebase export to BigQuery not populating traffic_source.name (campaign name) starting Feb 10th

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

We noticed an issue across all our projects starting Feb 10th where the `first_open` event contains an empty campaign name (`traffic_source.name` column). The `traffic_source.source` and `traffic_source.medium` columns contain the right values indicating the users are from Google Ads campaigns (`google` and `cpc` respectively).

Following is the BigQuery select (just replace the {project} and {ID}):

```
SELECT event_date, traffic_source.source, traffic_source.medium, traffic_source.name, count(*)
FROM `{PROJECT}.analytics_{ID}.events_202202*`
 WHERE event_name = 'first_open' AND traffic_source.medium = 'cpc' and traffic_source.name IS NULL
 group by 1,2,3,4
 order by 1,2,3,4
```

I've checked the first_open attribution on Firebase console and it seems to be fine. We suspect the issue is related to the export to BigQuery only.

Does anyone else notice this?

Comment: Hi @alechko, Upon checking, there are no outage or similar issue exporting to BigQuery. This is isolated and cannot be replicated here on Stackoverflow. I would suggest to contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: @marc-anthony-b Thanks, I've already opened a ticket on Firebase support. BTW I'm quite sure it's not isolated to our projects as I've confirmed it with a project from a different company.

Comment: We're having exactly the same issue

Comment: I've opened an issue on Bigquery support as instructed by Firebase support: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220464195
@Minh-HungNguyen would be great if you could star the issue and confirm that you are also experiencing this.